# MapStruct Problem binding to a class with getter and Builder classes

Tags: java, binding, lombok, mapstruct

I am using MapStruct in my project as a binding framework and I am facing problem binding objects.

Below is my LibraryResponse Class.

```
public class LibraryResponse{
  private String var1;
  private String var2;
  ...
  private String var20;
  //Setters and Getters for the 20 varibles using Lombok. These are auto generated
}
```

Below is my APIResponse Class.

```
public class APIResponse{
  private String var1;
  private String var2;
  ...
  private String var20;
  //Setters and Getters for the 20 varibles. These are auto generated

  public static Builder builder() { // Auto generated builder class
      return new Builder();
  }
  public static class Builder { // These are auto generated as well
    private String var1;
    private String var2;
    ...
    private String var20;
    public Builder withVar1(String var1) {
      this.var1 = var1;
      return this;
    }
    ...
    public Builder withVar20(String var20) {
      this.var20= var20;
      return this;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to bind LibraryResponse object to APIResponse object.

Following is my mapper class, but this not working as MapStruct is trying to find variable of builder class. I am getting compile warning "Unmapped target properties: withVar1,withVar2....withVar20"

```
@Mapper
interface APIMapper {
  APIResponse mapLibraryToAPI(LibraryResponse source);
}
```

The mapper is compiling fine if I use below mapper class (or) If I delete Builder class/methods from APIResponse and use above mapper class.

```
@Mapper
interface APIMapper {
  @Mapping(target="withVar1",source="var1")
  ...
  @Mapping(target="withVar20",source="var20")
  APIResponse mapLibraryToAPI(LibraryResponse source);
}
```

But I don't want to write 20 lines of code. Is there any way to tellMapStruct to use getters instead of Builder class?

Comment: https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-with-builders

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not using Lombok for your builder, because then you won't get those `with`-prefixed methods. And I think the prefix is the problem.

Comment: We use a modified version of Lombok and the pattern that I have mentioned above is a @Wither. https://projectlombok.org/features/With

Comment: When using the Lombok Wither then only the class methods are prefixed, nit the builder ones. Can you please provide your classes with the Lombok annotations as well?

Comment: can you try adding an empty constructor in the class? then maybe mapstruct will create a new APIResponse() using the empty constructor and use it to do the mapping. If it does not work then disable the builder using @Mapper(builder = @Builder(disableBuilder = true))

Comment: Please provide example with full set of annotations. But I suggest you adding Lombok's `@NoArgsConstructor`. then `APIResponse mapLibraryToAPI(LibraryResponse source);` should work like a charm as your names are matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Mapstruct Mapper which doesn't use builder methods on target type to create mapper methods.

NonBuilderMapperConfig.java

```
import org.mapstruct.Builder;
import org.mapstruct.MapperConfig;

@MapperConfig(builder = @Builder(disableBuilder = true))
public interface NonBuilderMapperConfig {
}
```

Now extend the mapper on which you want withers.

```
@Mapper(config = NonBuilderMapperConfig.class)
public interface APIMapper{

//Now all withers will be binded automatically
APIResponse mapLibraryToAPI(LibraryResponse source);
}
```

In case if you do not want Builder in your project at all and you are binding only @Wither in your project you can disable Builder by creating a file `META-INF/services/org.mapstruct.ap.spi.BuilderProvider` with value `org.mapstruct.ap.spi.NoOpBuilderProvider` in your project. Refer [Documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#mapping-with-builders) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Sharing in case someone else is looking for this but the above solution doesn't work for them (as it didn't for me) - but my use case is potentially slightly different:

- Target object does have the "whithers" setter methods (so when source field is "myField" corresponding target is "withMyField")
- However, we're using auto-builder frameworks (like Immutables and Lombok), so the Builder is fine/we don't want to disable it

What *did* work is the use of [MapStruct Accessor Naming Strategy](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#_custom_accessor_naming_strategy).

This is Example 104 from the above link:

```java
public class CustomAccessorNamingStrategy extends DefaultAccessorNamingStrategy {

    @Override
    public boolean isGetterMethod(ExecutableElement method) {
        String methodName = method.getSimpleName().toString();
        return !methodName.startsWith( "with" ) && method.getReturnType().getKind() != TypeKind.VOID;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSetterMethod(ExecutableElement method) {
        String methodName = method.getSimpleName().toString();
        return methodName.startsWith( "with" ) && methodName.length() > 4;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPropertyName(ExecutableElement getterOrSetterMethod) {
        String methodName = getterOrSetterMethod.getSimpleName().toString();
        return IntrospectorUtils.decapitalize( methodName.startsWith( "with" ) ? methodName.substring(  4 ) : methodName );
    }
}
```

I think if it's in same package as your code, it should just work - haven't tested this though. We're using it as an external package.

If it's an external library package, make sure to vend it out. E.g.:

Sample package structure:

```
src
|
 - my/lib/name/CustomAccessorNamingStrategy.java
 - META-INF/services/org.mapstruct.ap.spi.AccessorNamingStrategy
```

Make sure that `META-INF/services/org.mapstruct.ap.spi.AccessorNamingStrategy` path and naming is exact or it won't be discovered

Then inside the `org.mapstruct.ap.spi.AccessorNamingStrategy` you should have this 1 line:

```
my.lib.name.CustomAccessorNamingStrategy
```